# Could not find bcrypt-3.1.13 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound) when adding devise gem in a Rails Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, devise, rubygems

I'm currently getting `Could not find bcrypt-3.1.13 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)` when I install `gem 'devise'` from my Rails Docker.

[image: Screenshot]

My current gemfile is

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.0'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0.rc1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false
gem 'rack-cors'
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.0'
gem 'rake','12.3.2'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3'
gem 'devise'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

and my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
 db:
  image: postgres:alpine
  restart: always
  volumes:
   - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
 web:
  build: .
  restart: always
  command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
  volumes:
   - .:/myapp
  ports:
   - "3000:3000"
  depends_on:
   - db
```

when I run my application using `docker-compose up` I'm getting the error but when I run it using a normal `rails s` there's no error.

I'm currently using Rails `6.0.2.rc2` and Ruby `2.6.0`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work using this thread https://dev.to/k_penguin_sato/cache-rails-gems-using-docker-compose-3o3f